# How to sign aab bundle with new upload key (without key password)

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, fastlane, android-app-signing

Recently, we had to register a new upload key on our app in the google play store (internal track), though the setup seems a little different from our previous approach that requested a password on the key alias when creating a key using keytool on `.jks` format

We originally stored the `storeFile & storePassword` along with multiple `key<Flavor>Alias & key<Flavor>Password` in a `keystore.properties` file which worked fine, and our `build.gradle` looped over our product flavors assigning each signing config to the flavor.

Now though, when running this in the CLI as instructed by google play console to generate a new certificate:

```bash
keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks

keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore.jks
```

the upload key was created, but it did not prompt for a key password.

So now I'm wondering how to build the app without having it signed when running the `gradle bundle<Flavour>Release` command?

For more clarity on our current setup:

```bash
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystorePropertiesFileExists && keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    signingConfigs { }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId <application-id>
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", <application-id>
    }
    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        Staging { applicationId "<application-id>.staging" }
        RC { applicationId "<application-id>.rc" }
        Production {}
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug { signingConfig null }
        release {
            productFlavors.all { flavor ->
                flavor.signingConfig = android.signingConfigs.create("${flavor.name}")
                flavor.signingConfig.storeFile = rootProject.file(keystoreProperties["storeFile"])
                flavor.signingConfig.storePassword = keystoreProperties["storePassword"]
                flavor.signingConfig.keyAlias = keystoreProperties["keyAlias${flavor.name}"]
                flavor.signingConfig.keyPassword = keystoreProperties["keyPassword${flavor.name}"]
            }
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            debuggable false
        }
    }
```

We also use fastlane to handle our uploads with supply, are the specific commands (I can't see any) that would need to be amended for this?

Thanks!